# How to specify download location when open the full file download URL via chrome using Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm thinking about how to specify download location using javascript.
I got serveral the full file download URLs and use **window.open(url, '_blank');** to start download them. However, all these files will be downloaded to the Chrome default path. How do I do to let them download to different folders?

Comment: You can't. That would be a **huge** security issue. It would make little sense anyway as each of your clients could look really differently.

Comment: You can influence the download filename *only* (and even then it can be changed by the user), never the download *path*.

Comment: You can create an installer using InstallShield or any other tool that creates software packages. Did you ever seen something like this on regular websites? The answer is NO, and there's a reason for that. No need to ask the obvious

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is currently not possible.

> JavaScript doesn't have a file handling support unlike most languages.
>
> This is due to security reasons and how quickly JavaScript was built
>   in a short time with a lot of restrictions from Netscape.

Source: https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-code-in-JavaScript-to-download-my-files-to-a-specific-folder-where-I-want-to-save